# Creating a json write stream doesn't compile

Tags: json, zig

I am trying to use JSON in zig and I don't understand why this doesn't compile:

```
const file = std.fs.cwd().createFile("Hello", .{.read = true}) catch unreachable;
const stream = std.json.writeStream(std.fs.File.Writer, 5000000);
_ = stream;
```

The error:

```
error: parameter of type 'type' must be declared comptime
        pub fn init(stream: OutStream) Self {
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.huy.rocks/everyday/01-09-2022-zig-json-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std.json.writeStream` wants an instance of a write stream, you should pass to it `file.writer()` instead of `std.fs.File.Writer`.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: @taste01, the [`writeStream`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/f5068107cdf54f143a150feb5d500962ba98e963/lib/std/json/write_stream.zig#L226) function expects the first argument to be an object, it then gets its type (the `std.fs.File.Writer`). Don't confuse it with the [`WriteStream`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/f5068107cdf54f143a150feb5d500962ba98e963/lib/std/json/write_stream.zig#L18) function (which the previous one calls).